# WooCommerce - Moving Product Price to the Left of Add to Cart Button

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using the theme Salient and want to move the product price to the left of the add to cart button. Currently I have my product price above the button as you can see in the image below:
[image]

I already moved the price element around by adding some php to this custom plugin called "Snippets". It puts it right above the button rather than above the "Acrylic on Canvas" text. Here is the code:

```
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that now you just have to add the proper css. On both elements (price and button) place:

```
display: inline-block;
```

You can also try:

```
float: left;
```

Comment: It looks nice if I "float:left;" then "margin-right" the price, but I wanted to know if there was anyway to do it in php.

Comment: User interface is defined by HTML and CSS (client-side languages, such as js). With PHP you only define what is loaded from the server to the client (it's a server-side language)